# How to save as a gensim word2vec file?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I have two lists, A is a list of words, for example ["hello","world",......], Len(A) is 10000. List B contains the all pre-trained vectors corresponding to A, which is a [10000,512], 512 is the vector dimension. I want to convert two lists into gensim word2vec model format in order to load the model in later, such as `model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model")` how should I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you only have the words and their vectors, you don't quite have enough info for a full `Word2Vec` model (which includes other things like the internal neural network's hidden weights, and word frequencies).

But you can create a `gensim` `KeyedVectors` object, of the general kind that's in a `gensim` `Word2Vec` model `.wv` property. It has many of the helper methods (like `most_similar()`) you may be interested in using.

Let's assume your *A* list-of-words is in a more-helpfully named Python list called `words_list`, and your *B* list-of-vectors is in a more-helpfully named Python list called 'vectors_list`.

Try:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
kv = new KeyedVectors(512)
kv.add(words_list, vectors_list)
kv.save(`mywordvecs.kvmodel`)
```

You could then later re-load these via:

```
kv2 = KeyedVectors.load(`mywordvecs.kvmodel`)
```

(You could also use `save_word2vec_format()` and `load_word2vec_format()` instead of gensim's native `save()`/`load()`, if you wanted simpler plain-vectors formats that could also be loaded by other tools that use that format. But if you're staying within `gensim`, the plain `save()`/`load()` are just as good – and would be better if saving a more complex trained `Word2Vec` model, because they'd retain the extra info those objects contain.)

Comment: thx, but I got the error,'Word2VecKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'add', I am using gensim 3.4.0, and python 3.7

Comment: Yes, `add()` is a more-recent addition to `KeyedVectors`. Glad it’s working for you now!